# Resolve a dependency dynamically inside a gradle task

Tags: gradle

I am trying to build a gradle plugin, which does the following:

1. As part of one its tasks, it creates a new configuration
2. It adds a DefaultExternalModuleDependency to this configuration - more specifically, it constructs a dependency to the application server zip file (available on Nexus). This information can be overridden by the invoking project as well.
3. Tries to resolve this newly added dependency and then unpacks the file to a local folder

All of this was working well when I had the details hard coded in a build file, but it looks like adding dependencies as part of a task are not treated the same way as having that information available at the parsing time.

So my question is, how do I get the project to reload the configurations / dependencies?

The code looks like the following:

```
@TaskAction
void installAppserver() {
  Dependency dependency = new DefaultExternalModuleDependency(group,name,version)
  Configuration configuration = project.configurations.detachedConfiguration(dependency)
  configuration.setTransitive(false)
  configuration.files.each { file ->
    if (file.isFile() && file.name.endsWith('.zip')) {
      println 'Attempting to unzip: ' + file + ' into folder: ' + appServerFolder
      new Copy().from(project.zipTree(file)).into(appServerFolder).execute()
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the actual artifacts are not getting resolved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A task can't configure the build model (that's what plugins do). It's fine to create and resolve a detached configuration in a task. If this doesn't work, there is likely a problem with the task's code, or the dependency it tries to resolve. Note that dependencies can only be resolved if the correct repository(s) are defined.

Instead of `new DetaultExternalModuleDependency()` (which is an internal class), `project.dependencies.create()` should be used. Instead of `new Copy().execute()` (`Task#execute` must not be called from user code), `project.copy` should be used.

Comment: Nope. No luck. When I run the code in debug mode, I notice that the repositories are present; the correct repository is being used to lookup the dependency; TransientConfigurationBuilder says that it has loaded the 'resolved configuration results' - And then it stops! I am not sure on how to go about debugging this now. Any ideas?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing all the details. It's not a general problem, as many existing tasks already do the same as what you are trying to do. Perhaps have a look at the code quality plugins in the Gradle codebase.

Comment: I am debugging through the code and noticed that the 'DefaultModuleDescriptor.addArtifact()' method is never invoked when I try to resolve the configuration dynamically.

Comment: Never mind .. Found my mistake .. Wasn't specifying the file extension. On the other hand, I am still marking this as an answer as this discussion helped me clean up my plugin as well as look in the right place. Thanks Peter.